# Changing Connection String in C# programmatically

Tags: c#, connection-string

I need to make a connection setting in my system (changing the connection string in run time). I mean the user can set up and connect to any server they want. My question is, how can I retrieve the last connection string the user made in the connection setting and use it when the user re run the program?

So far this what I've made :

```
connect = "Data Source=" + Class1.DS.ToString() + ";Initial Catalog=" + Class1.IC.ToString() + ";Integrated Security= True;pooling=false;Connection Timeout=0;";
MessageBox.Show("Connection Made!");
this.Close();`(this is for the settings form)

 frmSettings settings = new frmSettings();
                    connectString = frmSettings.connect.ToString();
                    dbconnection = new SqlConnection(connectString);
                    dbconnection.Open(); //<--(and this is where I call the connection string after the set-up)
```

What will I do to retrieve the last connection string the user made? Any suggestions please help me..

Comment: Assuming you are limited to SQL Server, you should look at the SqlConnectionStringBuilder class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @GrantWinney the users only put the Data Source (Server Name) and Initial Catalog (Database Name) .. and they are entering the values on textboxes..

Comment: I suggest you to use a UDL file ;).

Comment: Mr. @GrantWinney can u show me how to do it?

Comment: Many thoughts come to mind; one is to store the user settings in a local database. You can also store a history of connections if you wish, allowing the user to pick any recent one.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using WinForm.  There are many options about saving settings such as registry, custom ini...etc. The easiest one I always try before going elsewhere is config file.

Add "System.Configuration" into your project reference.  Right click your project and "Add New Item", search for "config", you will see "Application Configuration File", add it.  Now you have a App.Config.

You can add items into the file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
    <add key="Config1" value="Foo" />
    <add key="Config2" value="Bar" />
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And to use it, you can do:

```
Configuration configManager = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var conf = configManager.AppSettings.Settings;
string val1 = conf["Config1"].Value;
```

You can play with the OpenExeConfiguration call to look for different locations depending on your YourApp.exe.config file, but you get the idea...

Comment: I need to save it in run time.. how can i make it? I think what you suggest is hard coded..

Comment: @Qwety you can call configManager.save() to save back to XML.

Comment: @Qwety Please consider this as an answer.